# Pass hashed password from $request->validated in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way I can create the user with the hashed password, not plain password?

```
public function post(StoreUserRequest $request) {
    User::create($request->validated());
    return redirect()->route('frontend.login')->with('message', 'Your account has been created!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the hashing docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/hashing

> You may hash a password by calling the make method on the Hash facade

```
public function post(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
    $userData = $request->validated();
    $userData['password'] = Hash::make($request->input['password']);
    User::create($userData);
    return redirect()->route('frontend.login')->with('message', 'Your account has been created!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to Hash your password? But also you can, because a hash in just a string. Your field password in DB, probably is a string too. You can use Laravel Auth too. This provide a full authentication system with one line on terminal

`php artisan make:auth`

Comment: This is changing my whole code, which isn't a solution, its a change.